# Xcode 11 Beta 5 not showing Swift 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have downloaded XCode 11 from the apple website and I am trying to upgrade my code to Swift 5.1 but XCode isn't giving met that option. Also, I don't see iOS 13 simulators available. I have never had this problem before so what am I missing? My OS was updated to MacOS Catalina

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is 5.1, SwiftUI is build on top of the Swift 5.1 and it depends on the many key futures it like Property wrapper, builders, etc.

Answer (score 41):

First of all note that the "Swift Language Version" dropdown doesn't select a compiler version, but rather a compatibility mode for the compiler to run in ([more on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283128/2976878)).

Arguably the dropdown menu is mislabelled in this case, as the "Swift 5" option really means "Swift 5.1" in Xcode 11. This can be demonstrated by running the following:

```
#if swift(<5.1)
print("Less than 5.1")
#else
print("At least 5.1")
#endif
```

You'll see that `At least 5.1` gets printed. Interestingly this means that there's actually no way to run a 5.1 compiler with a compatibility language version of 5.0.

Comment: This is confusing, since Xcode does make a distinction between Swift 4 and 4.2. When I installed Xcode 11, I expected to see Swift 5.1, not Swift 5.

Comment: @Greg Brown i guess there won’t be options > 5.0 because there is abi stability starting From 5.1 )

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 12.3 as well. It Shows 5.0 only.