# how to update the swift compiler version into 5.1?

Tags: swift, xcode11.3

I am trying to update the swift compiler language version to 5.1. But I am having the latest xcode version of Version 11.3.1 (11C504) Toolchain: Swift 5.1 Snapshot 2020-01-28 (a).

I downloaded the swift-5.1-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2020-01-28-a-osx package and installed but the is added in the toolchain. I couldn't see the required version in the compiler section.

So how to update that.

I have added the screen shot for more details

[image]

Comment: [Xcode 11.3.1 supports Swift 5.1.3 but not 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52819598/5133585), so I would assume "Swift 5" written there means Swift 5.1.3.

Comment: Here Swift 5 means all Swift 5.x versions. Until Apple explecitily adds something, which is now less likely to happen due to ABI Stability.

Comment: hey [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464533/xcode-11-beta-5-not-showing-swift-5-1) can answer your question.